# cifar100 with MobiletNetV2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train MobileNetV2 on CIFAR100 using keras.applications
Here is my code:

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')

x_test = x_test.astype("float32")
x_train = x_train.astype("float32")

x_test /=255
x_train /=255

y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,100)
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,100)
model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=(32,32,3),
                    alpha=1.0,
                    include_top=True,
                    weights=None,
                    classes=100)
epochs = 200
batch_size = 64
print('Using real-time data augmentation.')
    # This will do preprocessing and realtime data augmentation:
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        zca_epsilon=1e-06,  # epsilon for ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        shear_range=0.,  # set range for random shear
        zoom_range=0.,  # set range for random zoom
        channel_shift_range=0.,  # set range for random channel shifts
        # set mode for filling points outside the input boundaries
        fill_mode='nearest',
        cval=0.,  # value used for fill_mode = "constant"
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
        # set rescaling factor (applied before any other transformation)
        rescale=None,
        # set function that will be applied on each input
        preprocessing_function=None,
        # image data format, either "channels_first" or "channels_last"
        data_format=None,
        # fraction of images reserved for validation (strictly between 0 and 1)
        validation_split=0.0)
datagen.fit(x_train)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train,batch_size=batch_size),
                        epochs=epochs,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
                             )
```

The issue is with the validation accuracy, after 200 epochs the acc is almost 40%. 
I tried to fine_tune the optimizer/loss params but still the same. My guess is the dim of the input is too small for the model as the default is 224*224, however according to the documentation you could use whatever you want!

Any advice? (I do not want to change the dim of cifar100 to 224*224 because of some assumptions related to this experiment)!

Comment: Are you sure that it can go over 40% , is this a problem which normally reach higher acc?

Comment: MobileNet achieved remarkable results on imagenet, so it must classify cifar100 with very good acc!

Answer (score 0):

Some things that come to my mind...

- Check the data augmentation pipeline (`datagen`). It may be distorting the input too much and hence the model may be learning weird stuff instead of learning to classify the images
- Check also the training accuracy... Is it better than the validation? by how much?
- For me, 32x32 is small but I think you should even though get higher accuracy...